# My perfect background image

Tags: html, css, image, image-scaling, autosize

I currently have a page like this:

```css
body {
    background-image: url("http://placehold.it/1920x1200");
    min-height: 100vh;
    min-width: 100vw;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Cool Background Man</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
        </head>
        <body>
        </body>
    </html>
```

But I need the `background-image` to always be the smallest that it can be while preserving scaling (no stretching). This means that **AT ALL TIMES** either `width: 100vw` or `height: 100vh`, depending on the screen size. Also **AT ALL TIMES** the image will fill the screen. It will **NEVER** show any white space. The image must also **ALWAYS** show the top right corner, the image size should adjust relative to that.

To summarize, the image will always:

1. Have either `width: 100vw` or `height: 100vh`
2. Show the top right corner, and the size will adjust relative to that.
3. Fill the screen **for any screen size**. No white space **at all**.
4. Never stretch. Always preserve the scaling.

Comment: Maybe some JavaScript?

Comment: Make sure your image is a .svg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Background size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) is your friend. Browser support is [very good at 95% according to caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts)

body {
    background-image: url("http://placehold.it/1920x1200");
    min-height: 100vh;
    min-width: 100vw;
    overflow: hidden;
}

```css
body {
    background-image: url("http://placehold.it/1920x1200");
    min-height: 100vh;
    min-width: 100vw;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Cool Background Man</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
        </head>
        <body>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**UPDATE:** One way to do this that allows you to use CSS filters is to apply the background image to pseudo content and apply the filters to that:

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
body:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/1920x1200");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top right;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px); /* Or whatever filter you want */
  z-index: -1; /* Ensures it's behind the rest of the content */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Cool Background Man</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>

<body>
  Some content
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How would you do that with just an `img` not the whole body, because I need to apply filters to the image, and you cant do that for a background-image (I think)